Asymptotic formulation of Laguerre polynomials of real order
We have Fejer's asymptotic formula for an associated Laguerre polynomial laguerre(n,a,x) as given in below link.
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/a65232999dd61f4298266965f24f79d6d0923b05
which can be found here in section called Generalized Laguerre polynomials
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials
These asymptotic formulae are derived for integer values of $n$.
My question is, do these formulae work for $n$ a real number or a  rational number or are there other asymptotic formulae for this case ?

Think about Laguerre functions

@Claude Leibovici I couldn't figure it out :(

https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Laguerre_functions

@Claude Leibovici yes, but there is a generalization to real n by extending the nth derivative version of the Laguerre polynomials by using fractional derivatives.
